# AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'ents' in building NER using BERT

Tags: python, pandas, bert-language-model, named-entity-recognition

I'm trying to build a `NER` model using `Bert-base-NER` for a `tweets dataset` and ending up getting this error . Please help

This is what I have done

```
from transformers import AutoTokenizer, AutoModelForTokenClassification
from transformers import pipeline

tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained("dslim/bert-base-NER")
model = AutoModelForTokenClassification.from_pretrained("dslim/bert-base-NER")

nlp = pipeline("ner", model=model, tokenizer=tokenizer)

# ---------

def all_ents(v):
        return [(ent.text, ent.label_) for ent in nlp(v).ents]

df1['Entities'] = df['text'].apply(lambda v: all_ents(v))

df1.head()
```

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'ents'
```

Thank you for the help

Comment: Apparently `nlp(v)` is a list, not an object which has an attribute `ents`. You need to discover just what that list contains. Try printing it. Also -- look at the documentation for pipeline. It should discuss return type.

Comment: I'M new to this filed ..Can I know how to discover just what that list contains

Comment: You could try printing it, `print(nlp(v))` prior to the line which throws the error. If the list is too big to print, you could try something like `print(nlp(v)[:3])` to look at the first few items.

Comment: Maybe first use `print()` (and `print(type(...))`, `print(len(...))`, etc.) to see which part of code is executed and what you really have in variables. It is called `"print debuging"` and it helps to see what code is really doing.

Comment: Please help with the code

Comment: it seems you mix code from different modules - `.ents` exists in module `spacy` but not in `transformers`

Comment: Then Can I please know how it goes in transformers

Comment: use `print(nlp(v)` and you will see what you have. It doesn't have `.text` nor `.label_` but dictionary with `ent["entity"]`, `ent["score"]`, `ent["index"]`, `ent["word"]`, `ent["start"]`, `ent["end"]`. For more details you may have to read documentation or some tutorials for `transformers`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you mix code from different modules.

`.ents` exists in module `spacy` but not in `transformers`

```
#import spacy
import en_core_web_sm

nlp = en_core_web_sm.load()

doc = nlp('Hello World of Python. Have a nice day')

print([(x.text, x.label_) for x in doc.ents])
```

In `transformers` you should use directly `nlp(v)` but it gives directory with `ent["entity"], ent["score"], ent["index"], ent["word"], ent["start"], ent["end"]`

```
from transformers import AutoTokenizer, AutoModelForTokenClassification
from transformers import pipeline

tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained("dslim/bert-base-NER")
model = AutoModelForTokenClassification.from_pretrained("dslim/bert-base-NER")

nlp = pipeline("ner", model=model, tokenizer=tokenizer)

# ---------

import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'text': ['Hello World of Python. Have a nice day']
})

# ---------

def all_ents(v):
    #print(nlp(v))
    return [(ent['word'], ent['entity']) for ent in nlp(v)]

df['Entities'] = df['text'].apply(all_ents)

#df1['Entities'] = df['text'].apply(lambda v: [(ent['word'], ent['entity']) for ent in nlp(v)])

print(df['Entities'].head())
```